# How can I put range, min, max and value in the CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have a large number of sliders all declared similar to this example.

input   class = 'slider' id = 'Slider4' type = 'range' min = '0' max = '100' value = '0' onchange = 'Update(4)'

The 'slider' class contains things like width, height, opacity, etc, but it would simplify my code even more if the "type = 'range' min = '0' max = '100' value = '0'" part could also be put in the 'slider' class.

But my editor (Brackers) rejects this as invalid HTML.  Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to express the non-presentational features of the element using CSS.

Repeated chunks of HTML could be inserted using a template powered by whatever server-side programming language you are using (or even a client-side one).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using some javascript code to detect and add a class to your desired element based on your min and max value, you can only target the input type by css, like so:

```
input[type=range] { 
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks.  Server side is actually a little ESP8266 so trying to reduce code as much as possible without getting messy and this would have helped a lot if it could have been done.